# Why isn't this subview getting removed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

IBAction does nothing. Logs "Back" to console so the connection's OK. self.topView also does nothing when the IBAction is called

```
-(IBAction)loadSettingsView:(id)sender;

{

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"settingsView_iphone" owner:self options:nil]; 
    } else {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"settingsView_ipad" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:topView];
}

-(IBAction)loadMainView:(id)sender;
{
    [topView removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"back");

}
```

Comment: what is `topView` and how is it being assigned?

Comment: ...which IBAction does nothing?

Comment: Question is "Why isn't this subview getting removed?" The IBAction that does nothing loadMainView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I am not making too many assumptions here, but this should solve your problem. I am assuming `topView` is a member of the current class:

```
-(IBAction)loadSettingsView:(id)sender;

{

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        topView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"settingsView_iphone" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]; 
    } else {
        topView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"settingsView_ipad" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:topView];
}

-(IBAction)loadMainView:(id)sender;
{
    [topView removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"back");

}
```

Basically, the `loadNibNamed` method you are using is returning an array with all the top-level views in the nib. If you want a reference to these views (And here I am assuming there is one view in the nib), you need to actually assign your `topView` variable. Currently `topView` is probably nil, so your `removeFromSuperview` call is doing nothing.

Comment: ...That seems like an awful way to assign topView. I'd suggest using a IBOutlet....

Comment: That makes sense. So how would I go about making topView not nil?

Answer (score 0):

Fund a much easier solution. Simply created a new view in the main view's nib and attached an IBOutlet to it. Works like a dream.

```
-(IBAction)loadSettingsView:(id)sender;
{
        [self.view addSubview:settingsView];
}

-(IBAction)loadMainView:(id)sender;
{
    [settingsView removeFromSuperview];
}
```